# cmake: compile a shared library and executable

Tags: c, dll, cmake

I would like to build:

1. A shared library
2. An executable using the compiled shared library in point 1.

For the library, I have the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)
project(driver C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(LIB_PATH "../../libdriver")
include_directories(${LIB_PATH})
include_directories(driver ${LIB_PATH}/uart)

add_library(driver SHARED
        ${LIB_PATH}/libdriver.c
        ${LIB_PATH}/uart/uart.c)
```

I create the `LIB_PATH` variable, because the files needed for the lib compilation are outside of the tree.

Now I have my executable CMakeLists.txt and I would like to use the compiled previously dll file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)
project(proj_exe C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(LIB_PATH "../../libdriver") # so I have the headers
set(MAIN_PATH "../../project") # the main.c file located here

include_directories(${LIB_PATH})
include_directories(driver ${LIB_PATH}/uart)

# what to do now to compile the executable with the dll
```

Comment: Do you want both to be part of the same project, or compile them separately? Also are you trying to add 2 `CMakeLists.txt` files to the same directory? After all the `driver` include dir is uses the same relative path for both files...

Comment: Hi, I am initially trying to compile them as a single project, but making these to be possible to live on tgeir own makes more sense maybe. I am not trying to have 2 txt files in the same dir. I assume they exist in 2 separate subdirs, which are in the same dir.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to install the driver libs locally and use cmake's functionality to generate a import script. In the project using the lib, you can use `find_package` to add the dll as imported target allowing you to link it using `target_link_library`:

```
add_library(driver SHARED
        ${LIB_PATH}/libdriver.c
        ${LIB_PATH}/uart/uart.c)

# attach the info to the target here
target_include_directories(driver PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${LIB_PATH}>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${LIB_PATH}/uart>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/uart>
)

install(TARGETS driver EXPORT driver
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
)

# usually there's a lib just containing the public headers
# that can be copied, but yours seems to contain the source files too;
# not enough info though to separate headers from sources though, so we'll just copy everything 
install(DIRECTORY ${LIB_PATH}/ DESTINATION include)
install(EXPORT base DESTINATION cmake FILE base-config.cmake)
```

After building you should be able to do

```
cmake --install build_dir --prefix install_path
```

This allows you use `find_package` to import the files from the install directory, assuming you've added it to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`

```
cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=install_path -S ... -B ...
```

```
find_package(driver REQUIRED CONFIG)

add_executable(foo ...)

target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE driver)
```

You may need to adjust the paths in the description a bit to point use the correct locations relative to the current working directory...

Comment: Thabks for the answer- this seems a bit too much. I am not trying to specify a build script as such, but configure a develipment environment (i.e. CLion)- I havent mentioned that, sorry. So in this case I dont know if I should "install" the lib. I just need a 2 step build in which I first build the lib, and then build the executable with the output lib. I can move files around if having them out of the tree is an issue.